# Can the group of homotopy classes of maps into S^3 be noncommutative?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $[X,S^3]$ be the set of homotopy classes of maps from the pointed CW complex X to the pointed 3-sphere.  The group structure on S^3 endows this set with a  group structure.  Is this group ever noncommutative?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, by Yoneda's lemma.  To generalize a bit, you have a group object $G$ in some category with finite products, and you ask whether the functor it represents is pointwise abelian.  This is the same as asking whether two natural transformations $[-,G\times G]=[-,G]\times[-,G]\to[-,G]$ are equal (one being $(f,g)\mapsto f\cdot g$ and the other being $(f,g)\mapsto g\cdot f$).  By Yoneda, this is this case iff the representing maps $G\times G\to G$ are equal.  That is, the group $[X,G]$ is always abelian iff the multiplication map on $G$ is itself commutative.  In the case of $G=S^3$ in the homotopy category of spaces, the group operation is not (homotopy-)commutative, though I don't know an easy proof of that off the top of my head.

If you want an explicit example of an $X$ that makes $[X,G]$ nonabelian, you just have to unravel the proof of Yoneda's lemma.  That means you set $X=G\times G$ and consider the identity map $G\times G\to G\times G$, which corresponds the two projection maps $p_0,p_1\in[G\times G,G]$ when you identify $[G\times G,G\times G]=[G\times G,G]\times [G\times G,G]$.  So in your case, the group $[S^3\times S^3, S^3]$ is nonabelian, and in particular the two projection maps do not commute.

Comment: Eric, if $[S^3 \times S^3,S^3]$ is a noncommutative group, which noncommutative group is it?  (It looks like an extension of a subgroup of $[S^3$ wedge $S^3,S^3] = \mathbf{Z}+\mathbf{Z}$ by a quotient of $\pi_1([S^5,S^3]) = \mathbf{Z}/12$ to me.)  Which element is $gh$ and which element is $hg$?

Comment: That's a great question that I hope someone else can answer!

Comment: That $S^3$ is not homotopy commutative was apparently proved in [Samelson,H.,"Groups and wpaces of loops, Comm.Math.Helv.,28,278-87 (1954)]

Comment: @SpecialUnit2, why a subgroup of $Z\oplus Z$ and not the whole thing, and why a quotient of $Z/12$ and not the group itself?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, he was considering a certain long exact sequence from which it was not a priori clear that the corresponding maps are surjective and injective. They are, however, consider my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160297/what-is-the-group-of-pointed-homotopy-classes-of-maps-from-s3-times-s3-to/160307#160307

Comment: @AchimKrause, yup, that's what I had in mind. The long exact sequence arising from applying $[-,S^3]$ to the long coexact sequence of maps starting in $S^3\vee S^3\to S^3\times S^3\to\text{cone}\to\text{etc}$.

Comment: You can start one step further to the left, since $S^3\times S^3$ can be built from $S^3\vee S^3$ by attaching a 6-cell. So the maps you need to check in order to get a short exact sequence from that long one are $S^5 \rightarrow S^3\vee S^3$ and its suspension. The suspension is homotopic to zero (cf section 4.I in Hatcher), and the induced map of the unsuspended one vanishes as well on $[S^3\vee S^3,S^3]$, since suspending from $\pi_5(S^3)$ to $\pi_6(S^4)$ is injective.